# Error when using r.series in a python script

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I’m writing a tool script in python and at a certain point I want to use the GRASS tool r.series. I want the algorithem to read all raster files from a folder and calculate the maximum with r.series. The thing is I’m getting the error: *“Wrong parameter value: None”* when using the code below:

```
##RasterMaxFinder=name
##Select_directory=Folder
##Save_results=Folder

import glob, os, processing

list = ( Select_directory + "/" + "*.tif" )

processing.runalg('grass7:r.series', list ,False,6,'-10000000000,10000000000',None,30.0, Save_results + "/" + "Output.tif")
```

It must have something to do with the extend, but I can't figure out what. When I'm using the tool directly in QGIS, erverything works fine. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the extent probably has to be explicitly defined before you can run the algorithm. Seen a few posts about this. The following *might* work (note that I used `grass:r.series` and not `grass7:r.series`):

```
##RasterMaxFinder=name
##Select_directory=Folder
##Save_results=Folder

import glob, os, processing
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer, QgsRectangle

os.chdir(Select_directory)
list = []
extent = QgsRectangle()
extent.setMinimal()
for raster in glob.glob("*.tif"):
    fileInfo = QFileInfo(raster)
    baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(raster, baseName)
    # Combine raster layers to list
    list.append(rlayer)
    # Combine raster extents
    extent.combineExtentWith(rlayer.extent())

# Get extent    
xmin = extent.xMinimum()
xmax = extent.xMaximum()
ymin = extent.yMinimum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()
# Run algorithm
processing.runalg('grass:r.series', list ,False,6,'-10000000000,10000000000',"%f,%f,%f,%f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),30.0, Save_results + "/" + "Output.tif")
```

Comment: Well that looks good but I get the error „Error: Wrong parameter value: []”. I run it with “grass7:r.series”

Comment: @Miron - Forgot to mention that I haven't used this tool before so I guessed that the minimum extent would be the combined extent of all rasters (maybe I'm wrong?). I tested it with several rasters in the same folder and got a result but this is with `grass6`. I do not have `grass7` installed so cannot test this but I wouldn't expect there to be that much difference for it to cause an error. Not sure if I could help with much more, apologies!

Comment: My mistake, works like a charm, thank you very much!

Comment: @Miron - Most welcome buddy but what was the mistake if I may ask? ;)

Comment: Since this is the second step my processing model I integrated the code in my model and confused the Input and Output folder ;)

Comment: @Miron - Ahh gotcha =)

Comment: @Joseph - Is there a way to make the same with the grass:r.series by using "##1=multiple raster" and "##maximum=output raster" instead of  "##Select_directory=Folder" and "##Save_results=Folder"? I mean without using folders but loaded rasters?

Comment: @Nico_77 - I don't see why it shouldn't work, you would probably need to adjust the code a bit by getting raster information from the loaded rasters instead of from the directory. I suggest you ask this as a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), hopefully others can advise :)