# Concerning "Error when using r.series in a python script"

Tags: qgis, python, raster, pyqgis, statistics

Based on the "Error when using r.series in a python script" discussion ([Error when using r.series in a python script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187643/error-when-using-r-series-in-a-python-script/187650?noredirect=1#comment299230_187650)) and based upon the solution given by Joseph I tried to make the same but by using a loades set of rasters and saving the result as temporary file. I made the following script but it doesn't work to me. Any Idea to fix it?

```
##RasterMaxFinder=name
##1=multiple raster
##maximum=output raster

import glob, os, processing
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer, QgsRectangle

raster = processing.getObject(1)

list = []
extent = QgsRectangle()
extent.setMinimal()

for raster in 1:
    fileInfo = QFileInfo(raster)
    baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(raster, baseName)

    # Combine raster layers to list
    list.append(rlayer)

    # Combine raster extents
    extent.combineExtentWith(rlayer.extent())

# Get extent    
xmin = extent.xMinimum()
xmax = extent.xMaximum()
ymin = extent.yMinimum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()

# Run algorithm
processing.runalg('grass:r.series', list ,False,6,'-10000000000,10000000000',"%f,%f,%f,%f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),0.0, maximum)
```

Comment: What happens when you run the script? Do you receive no output, errors?

Comment: I get the following message: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **strings** for naming objects instead of *integers* as this could cause confusion. The following script runs for me which use the following line to split the multiple input rasters:

```
layers = input.split(';')
```

---

```
##Example=name

##input=multiple raster
##maximum=output raster

import glob, os, processing
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer, QgsRectangle

layers = input.split(';')
list = []
extent = QgsRectangle()
extent.setMinimal()

for raster in layers:
    fileInfo = QFileInfo(raster)
    baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(raster, baseName)
    # Combine raster layers to list
    list.append(rlayer)
    # Combine raster extents
    extent.combineExtentWith(rlayer.extent())    

# Get extent    
xmin = extent.xMinimum()
xmax = extent.xMaximum()
ymin = extent.yMinimum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()

# Run algorithm
processing.runalg('grass:r.series', list ,False,6,'-10000000000,10000000000',"%f,%f,%f,%f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),0.0, maximum)
```

Comment: YES! Indeed, it works that way!

Comment: @Nico_77 - Awesome, glad it works :)